# No viable overloaded operator[] for custom class

Tags: c++, class, vector

I've written custom subclass of std::vector:

```
template <class T>
class CustVec : public vector<vector<T>> {

public:

    T& operator [](const pair<int, int> pos) {
        return (*this)[pos.first][pos.second];
    }
};
```

But I've got an error `No viable overloaded operator[] for type 'CustVec<pair<int, int>>'`". How to fix it?

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: Don't inherit from standard containers. Instead, use composition.

Comment: The problem is that `(*this)[pos.first]` looks like a recursive call, but with the wrong parameter.

Comment: @Valentin, Xcode 7.1, but problem appears on other compilers too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are hiding the base class `operator[]` by declaring a new operator. As usual, this hides similar names from an outer scope.

You can make it visible again by explicitly importing the name by

```
using vector<vector<T>>::operator[];
```

Perhaps putting that in the private section, in order not to make it publicly accessible

```
template <class T>
class CustVec : public vector<vector<T>> {

    using vector<vector<T>>::operator[];

public:

    T& operator [](const pair<int, int> pos) {
        return (*this)[pos.first][pos.second];
    }
};
```